# Finding the GLRT for a one-sided hypothesis using uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

## The Problem

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim U(\theta, 5)$ where $0 < \theta < 5$ with pdf

$$
f(x;\theta) = \dfrac{1}{5-\theta} \quad \theta < x < 5
$$

Find the generalized likelihood ratio test for testing $H_0 : \theta = 4$ vs. $H_1 : \theta > 4$.  Determine the critical region if $\alpha = 0.05$.

## My attempt

For my own understanding, another way to write the pdf is $\frac{1}{5-\theta}\cdot I(x\in(\theta, 5))$.  Since we're dealing with the GLRT, we need to first find the test statistic of the following form:

$$
\lambda(x) = \dfrac{\sup_{H_0} L(\theta | x)}{\sup_{H_0 \cup H_1} L(\theta | x)}
$$

To find the supremums, we find the MLE of $f$ for both the restricted $H_0$ and unrestricted $H_0 \cup H_1$.  The likelihood is

$$
L(\theta | x) = \dfrac{1}{(5-\theta)^n}\cdot I(x_i\in(\theta, 5))
$$

**Restricted:** We are effectively given the cut off for $\theta$ so our MLE is just $\frac{1}{(5-4)^n} = 1$ for $x_i\in (4,5)$.  Maybe I am misunderstanding something here, but I don't think we need to worry about the $x_i$'s.

**Unrestricted:** This is where I get confused... We can take the log-likelihood and get the MLE for $\theta$ but it is unnecessary since we can directly see that the likelihood will be maximized when $\hat{\theta} = 5$ (I think approaches it is more accurate).

## My issue

I know that the numerator of my test statistic $\lambda(x)$ is 1.  I am unsure of what the denominator should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your restricted likelihood is generally correct, but we need to keep track of the indicators--that's why you rewrote the density that way to begin with.

The likelihood function given the sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is
$$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) =\frac{1}{(5-\theta)^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1(\theta < x_i < 5) = (5-\theta)^{-n} \mathbb 1(\theta < x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} < 5),$$ where we have used the order statistics $x_{(1)} = \min_i x_i$ and $x_{(n)} = \max_i x_i$ for convenience.  This also implies that $x_{(1)}$ is a sufficient statistic.

Then the restricted likelihood under $H_0$ is

$$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x, H_0) = \mathcal L(4 \mid \boldsymbol x) = \mathbb 1(4 < x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} < 5).$$  It is, strictly speaking, not identically $1$, because we must also have a sample whose observations must lie in the interval $(4, 5)$.

The unrestricted likelihood under the union of hypotheses $H_0 \cup H_1$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x, H_0 \cup H_1) 
&= \mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) \mathbb 1 (4 \le \theta < 5) \\
&= (5-\theta)^{-n} \mathbb 1(4 \le \theta < x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} < 5).
\end{align}$$
Now we maximize this likelihood by noting that $4 \le \theta < x_{(1)}$ is the relevant restriction.  Since $(5-\theta)^{-n}$ is a monotonically increasing function of $\theta$ on the interval $(-\infty, 5)$, it now becomes apparent that $$\sup_{H_0 \cup H_1} \mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = \begin{cases} (5-x_{(1)})^{-n}, & 4 < x_{(1)} < 5 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ and this in fact makes intuitive sense:  since $x_{(1)}$ represents in a fashion an upper bound on what value $\theta$ is permitted to take, we expect that the likelihood under $H_0 \cup H_1$ would have a supremum that is a function of $x_{(1)}$.  Hence

$$\lambda(\boldsymbol x) = \lambda(x_{(1)}) =  (5 - x_{(1)})^n, \quad 4 < x_{(1)} < 5.$$  The test statistic is not defined if $x_{(1)} \le 4$ because we cannot observe such a sample under the condition $\theta \ge 4$.

I leave it to you to compute the critical region for such a test.

Comment: Shoot, it's those darn indicators that messed me up.  I understand the overall idea now.  That said, I still have one question... Just speaking off the cuff, wouldn't a $\theta$ approaching 5 be what maximizes the likelihood value?  I am struggling to wrap my head around the fact that the smallest order statistic does the maximization and not the largest one.

Comment: @392781 Let's look at an example.  Suppose I picked a $\theta$, and then drew five numbers uniformly at random in the interval $(\theta, 5)$.  Then I told you the sample was $(4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.9)$.  Would it make any sense for you to say, for example, $\theta = 4.99999$?  Of course not:  $\theta$ cannot be that large because one of the numbers in the sample is $4.5$, and since this number was drawn from $(\theta, 5)$, we know $\theta \le 4.5$.  That's the crucial information that the sample is telling you about $\theta$ that allows you to make an inference about its value.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  Yeah this makes sense because technically, $\theta$ can be a lot smaller (like $\theta = 1$) which would make the likelihood smaller as well and hence not maximal.  It's all about that restriction.  I think the fact that the restriction is coming from the lower boundary is what messes with my head.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more thing of note: the restricted likelihood is $(4 < x_{(1)} \dots)$ whereas the unrestricted likelihood is $(4 \leq x_{(1)} \dots)$.  Shouldn't the final test statistic be in the region of $4 < x_{(1)} < 5$.  Otherwise wouldn't the test statistic just equal zero based on the restricted case's indicator when $x_{(1)} = 4$?

Comment: @392781 I might have been a bit sloppy about my inequalities--I am going to make some revisions to clarify.  You are correct; it should be $4 < x_{(1)} < 5$.